# Django: How to fetch data from a text file after every 60 seconds using JQuery?

Tags: django, jquery, django-templates, django-views

There is a text file in which the data is being written after, say, every 10 seconds. I want to display the data in the text file to user after every 60 seconds. I know I should be using Jquery/Ajax for this, but I am very much new to it. Any help on the template and view would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use setInterval

```
function showData(){
      $.getJSON(url, data, function (data, textStatus){
        // show the data
      });
    }

setInterval(showData, 60 * 1000);
```

Then have the url point to a view in Django which will read the file and return data as JSON.

Comment: `.getJSON()` isn't necessary if you just want to grab the text of the file.

Comment: @JosephMornin agreed.

Answer (score 0):

If Django is generating `http://your.domain/yourfile`, you can grab the contents of that page like this:

```
function getData() {
    $.get('http://your.domain/yourfile', function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }, 'text');
}

setInterval(getData, 60000);
```